# How to extract a substring from a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string of the following format:

```
var str1="tag:youtube.com,2008:video:VrtMalb-XcQ";
```

From this I need to extract the last part i.e. `VrtMalb-XcQ`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Take a look here: use the lastIndexOf on 'x' and use the substring method.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp

Answer (score 5):

What you need to know is the index of the last `:`. This can be achieved by using `lastIndexOf`

```
var str1="tag:youtube.com,2008:video:VrtMalb-XcQ";
var result = str1.substr(str1.lastIndexOf(':') + 1);
```

The `+ 1` is there because otherwise you would also get the colon itself in the string.

This is really the fastest approach to do it, and requires the least memory.

Answer (score 2):

use `split` and `pop`:

```
var str1="tag:youtube.com,2008:video:VrtMalb-XcQ";
str1.split(':').pop()
```

Comment: It is totally unnecessary to split the whole thing when all you need is the index of the last ':'

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg ... why it's unnecessary?? it's just the simple and short solution, thats works great

Comment: It is a waste of CPU power and memory. It is doing more job than is really required (small waste, but still a waste)

Comment: As I said: It is a small waste, but still a waste. It definitely gets the job done, but it's not the most optimal way.

Answer (score 0):

```
 "tag:youtube.com,2008:video:VrtMalb-XcQ".replace(/.*:/, "")
```

Comment: Using regex for this? Seriously? I don't think this is a good solution

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Not worth a downvote, it does work

Comment: @JuanMendes Sorry, I'm way too active on Code Review to do anything else. Additionally, there is no description at all, just a code dump.

Comment: why not regex? it's clean and simple.